# Why did media files stop loading on my macbook?

Tags: media

The issue was resolved by restarting my macbook but I just wanna know what happened.

Basically, youtube stopped working. I tried twitch and videos are just not working and stuck on loading but the internet is fast. I tried other browsers and the same thing happened.

I tried a video already downloaded on my macbook and the video just didn't work. I tried soundcloud, spotify, an mp3 file.

I just couldn't see any solution online to my issue so I restarted the macbook and it's working just fine now.

If anyone experienced this or has any clue what happened then I would really appreciate an answer.

Thank you

Comment: I am voting to close the question as unrelated to programming nor tags you mentioned. Fact that spotify is not working does not make it into the audio category :).

Answer (score 1):

Though it is hard to pinpoint what exactly caused these problems to occur, we know that it is a bug that caused the computer's system memory to get corrupted. It could be an update that requires a restart, it could be a program that closes unexpectedly which caused the bug it could even be the noise (radiation) from your surrounding. Again, very hard to pinpoint.

But with the restart of your computer, you are essentially erasing your memory (RAM) and starting brand new. That means your corrupted memory will be erased with it. When you boot up your computer again, your previous memory will be replaced with stable memory from your hard drive.